# Is there an easier way to debug Spring Boot in Eclipse Oxygen (4.7.0)

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, spring-boot

I recently switched IDE's going from MyEclipse to Eclipse Oxygen (4.7.0).  When working in MyEclipse I would debug a spring boot project using the "Spring Boot App" option which would run the application and allow me to debug it.  I could then stop the application through MyEclipse. In Eclipse Oxygen I do not have this menu item.  Instead the process is much more complicated.

Currently what I have to do in Eclispe Oxygen is start the project with the spring-boot:run goal, and with the debug configuration below.  I then need to run a Remote Java Application pointing at the same port. ([Instructions here](https://javapapers.com/core-java/java-remote-debug-with-eclipse/))  My project will run and stop at break points. When I then try to shut down the project, I have to terminate it and disconnect it. I then have to go into command prompt, run  taskkill /F /PID (PID of Process) to totally terminate the process.

This whole process is kind of a hassle.  I was wondering if there is a better way to run a spring boot app in Eclipse Oxygen, or if I should look into a different IDE.  I had attempted to install the [Spring Tools 4 suite](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/spring-tools-4-aka-spring-tool-suite-4) but when I drag and drop it to eclipse I get a red cancel box and nothing else happens.

Any suggestion is appreciated. Thanks!

```
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <jvmArguments>
                    -Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=8888
                </jvmArguments>
            </configuration>
```

[image]

Comment: It looks like you didn't install the Spring Tools. You can do that, or you can simply do Run As Java Application.

Comment: As @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- mentioned, your application class is a Java Application. You can just Debug it.

Comment: I will give the spring tool suite another shot tomorrow.  And also @nitind, you are correct. If I debug my main spring applicaion class as a Java Applicarion it seems to work fine and I can stop at break points. Thanks!

Comment: Note that Spring Tool Suite _is_ Eclipse, just pre-bundled with some extra plugins. You can install those same plugins from the Marketplace.

Answer (score 0):

If it isn't obvious by now, just go to the Marketplace (Help->Eclipse Marketplace...), enter "Spring" in the filter, and install the newest available "Spring Tools".

However, note that Eclipse Oxygen is a quite old version of Eclipse.  Unless there is a specific question of compatibility, you really should be using the latest version of Eclipse, which today is 2020-06.

Comment: it actually doesn't show up in market place for this version of eclipse. I found a download for it which I linked in my post above.-but I was unable to get it to install via drag and drop. I will mess with it more soon.